# iOS - remove trailing zeros from float WITHOUT converting to String?

Tags: ios, formatting, floating-point-precision, xctest

I would like to remove trailing zeros from a float.
I found multiple posts, but **all answers suggest converting a float to NSString and using NSFormatter**.

While this might be good in most cases, I am performing XCTests and I need the values in float - converting generated String back to float does not give correct results.

For input:

```
arg0 = 0.0001;
arg1 = 0.0011;
```

I would like a result of `0.0012`, but the addition `arg0 + arg1` gives the answer of `0.01200` which in turn generates a failing test for XCTest Case.

My method for adding numbers is the simpliest possible:

```
-(float)addNumber:(float)first toNumber:(float)second {

    return first + second;
}
```

And the test case as well:

```
- (void)testAddition3 {

    arg0 = 0.0001;
    arg1 = 0.0011;

    result = [vc addNumber:arg0 toNumber:arg1];

    XCTAssertEqual(result, 0.0012, @"Addition incorrect!");
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What does your code look like at the moment? it's kinda hard to figure out why you're getting this result from a black box perspective.
Also, why would these "trailing zeroes" be a problem unless you're displaying the number somewhere (which would have to be as a string)?

Comment: Edited my post, please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem is that floating point math is not exact - some numbers cannot be precisely represented in binary, and due to tiny rounding errors and the such, you can't be certain of the result. For a (contrived) example, 1.0 + 1.0 = 1.99999.. This makes things like equality difficult.

The typical way you compare two floating point numbers is comparing within some error (typically called epsilon).
The function you want is `XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy`, which will compare two floats with a given precision

Comment: No problem. You might also want to check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713800/xctassertequalwithaccuracy-not-working) SO link for "XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy not working"

Answer (score 3):

Change the assertion to use **XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy** rather than **XCTAssertEqual**.

> XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy. Generates a failure when the difference between expression1 and expression2 is greater than accuracy. This test is for scalars such as floats and doubles, where small differences could make these items not exactly equal, but works for all scalars.

Comment: I managed to figure it out couple of minutes before your answer, but than you, it solved my problem! :)